# Jmeter LOGIN and navigation using multiple logins in CSV file

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have to do following different http request in 1 thread.
1. Navigate to URL
2. Post user id and pwd(using Csv file)
3. Get the home screen
4. Navigate to search screen
I use Csv file to pass parameters. When I run with 1 user 2 times , post request access 2 login details. But Get Home screen is shown only for 1 login. It is not getting in to loop.
Is this because these are different http requests and need to be under any controllers?

Comment: please add the screenshot of the Test Plan (expand all the elements and take screenshot). In normal cases, it should work.

Comment: Thanks Naveen ! I actually found that another Get Screen Path was using the generated Value from Login Post. Fixed it and now it works. Thanks!